# Alternative for form Action to call a payment service

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services

Is there any working alternative or replacement using jquery or webservice for form action to call payment service like this :

```
<form name="ipg" action="https://pay.doku.com/DokuSuite/Channel" method="post" data-ajax="false">
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Your question is not clear at all.

Comment: Additionally, _why_ do you want an alternative to form action?

Comment: i want to make it more dynamic when i call the service, by moving it on a function or method.

Comment: on form submit handler you can do your work and finally submit it

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax to call your service (this service can be written in any server language):

In javascript you can create a function to cal your service through ajax with JQuery:

```
btnExecute_onclick = function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://pay.doku.com/DokuSuite/Channel",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            //parameters here
            anyParameterName: 'foo'
        },
        success: function( data ) {
            // do anything you want with data received from server
            // here I'm just showing the result in a div
            $( "#anyDiv" ).html( "Server return here: " + data + "" );
        }
    });

}
```

In the html you can have a button like this:

```
<input type="button" id="btnExecute" onclick="btnExecute_onclick()">
```

You can take input from the user by form tags like input type text and send as parameters in your ajax call.
You can receive in the success function, the return from the server.

Look at the [ajax JQuery function api here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: I've tried it the way you suggest but it did not work, as well as add service refrence to the project, I do not know whether this was due to cross domain issues

Comment: It's dificult to help without seeing your code and without a better description of your problem. My answer solves the problem for a more dynamic approach then using a form to call a service hosted in a server.